# Reading a txt file to plot a graph (c++)

Tags: c++

I am new to c++. I want to read this .txt file and plot it out with c++.
I have a series of data that look like this.

```
4.299999989e+001    -3.682989627e-002   -3.635308705e-003   5.932495371e-002
4.300000089e+001    -2.672462724e-002   -7.527103298e-004   7.454365492e-002
4.300000189e+001    -6.389028858e-003   3.274697345e-003    5.433369055e-002
4.300000289e+001    1.632947288e-002    5.136939231e-003    3.248876333e-002
4.300000389e+001    3.278360888e-002    5.786722526e-003    -1.292655012e-003
4.300000489e+001    3.676251322e-002    3.845411120e-003    -2.506720088e-002
```

I have use fstream to open and read it. However i been getting error regarding memory problem.

My code look like this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
char line[50];
fstream file;
file.open ("C\\Users\\Zhi Sheng\\Desktop\\Data\\example.txt", ios::in );
file.getline(line,50);
cout << line;
file.close();
return 0;
}
```

May I know what went wrong with it?

Comment: increase char array `line` size, but better to use `std::getline` instead of `ifstream.getline`

Comment: The first line in your example has 76 characters. What was your output? What did you expect it to be? Do you eventually want those numbers in floats or doubles? Why not read them that way from the start? Instead of saying `"However i been getting error regarding memory problem"` tell us exactly what the problem is. Be specific and explain your goal if that is what you want help with implementing.

Comment: You probably should use `std::string line;` instead of `char line[50];`

Comment: or if the line always has 4 floats each separated by whitespace. `std::array<double,4> data; while (file >> data[0] >> data[1] >> data[2] >> data[3]) { // do something with data }`

Comment: I don't know why tags "embedded systems" and "Code Composer" were removed by @Clifford since they both were relevant for this question although it was not apparent from the question text. It became apparent through my conversation with OP through comments. Any of the "embedded-systems" and "Code Composer" people with Texas Instruments experience were able to help but removing those tags actively disabled them in doing so.

Comment: @IvanG  You said it yourself - because _"it [is] not apparent from the question text"_ why the tags were there.  It should not be necessary to read the comments to the question let alone _your_ answer for the question to be complete.  If you add the tags you also have to fix the question.  But given the solution the OP has mentioned in comment to your answer, the question is invalid and entirely lacks the information necessary to diagnose the specific issue.  I doubt the question will be improved now the OP has figured his error, and such a question has little community benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be, that `cout` tries to read characters unless it sees `\0` char. But, as for your example, the last byte won't be set to 0 (meaning the last character won't be `\0`) and it will run out of the array. Try increasing the size of the buffer at least by one and set the last char to `\0`.

## Edit

For your particular case, if you want to read the data as numbers (not strings), try out using `operator >>` on doubles:

```
double value;
my_stream >> value;
```

this will try to fetch the next double value into the `value` variable.